# Why ReflectionProperty->setValue() method didn't set property, but instead tries to set field? And what to do if i need to set property value?

Tags: php, reflection

I written simple test that use Reflection to set property of some class instance:

```
namespace Rufanov\PHP\Tests
{
    class LaboratoryMouse
    {
        /** @var string */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $name
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = 'The awesome ' . $name;
        }
    }

    class ReflectionTests extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        public function testSetValue()
        {
            $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass('Rufanov\PHP\Tests\LaboratoryMouse');

            /** @var ReflectionTests $cat */
            $cat = $reflectionClass->newInstance();

            $nameProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('Name');
            $nameProperty->setValue($cat, 'Felix');

            $this->assertEquals('The awesome Felix', $cat->getName());
        }
    }
}
```

It fails...

I have experience with other object-oriented programming languages, that also have reflection. And so i've expected from PHP that it will set property value. If you want from OOP language to set property value for you, it should find object property and set it's value by calling setter method, right?

But PHP does something different here - it tries to set FIELD value, that is not exists as expected. Why??? How can i set value of some property in PHP if i only know it's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is defined by the `private $name;`, not by the two methods that indirectly set and get that value. The property class simply doesn't know that *you* consider these two functions the getters and setters for `$name`. It doesn't care either, it just provides access to the class' and/or object's properties.

What you can do, if you follow a consistent naming schema, is to use this syntax:

```
$cat->{'set' . $property}('Fritz');
```

(I think that works. If not, you might have to `call_user_method()`.)

A completely different approach is to implement `__get()` and `__set()` for your class. Using these, you can intercept property access, which makes the separate getters and setters obsolete.

Comment: $name is not property - it's just field(instance variable). it should be private there. Property is an OOP languages is a feature that allows you make special class member that looks like public instance variable to external class users, but really implemented as several methods - they allows you to do more complicated things than just setting or retrieving some instance variable values. set* and get* methods don't do this. __get() and __set() can do this, but they have too many responsibilities, using them will result in ugly unmaintainable code.

Comment: So, seems like PHP don't really have properties like i expected from OOP language, and ReflectionProperty->setValue() is a just useless misnamed method, because it can't set value of any property.. It's sad.. Well, thanks.. Question closed.